# Create exact same Tufte-style headers

Tags: fonts, header-footer, tufte, definition

I would like to have the **exact same** headers, fonts etc. **as in the "tufte-book"** documentclass for all my `\chapters`, `\sections` and `\subsections` etc. using the "book" documentclass. Therefore, I have tried:

- Using "tufte-book" documentclass but removing the margin. Impossible ???
- Trying to find the definitions in the tufte-book and redefining new commands for all my `\sections` etc.  in the  "book" documentclass
- Using "book" documentclass and playing around with these packages:
  `\usepackage{mathpazo}`, `\usepackage[scaled=0.90]{helvet}`  `\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}`, `\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}`.

This did not output the exact same fonts as in tufte-book, however. So, my questions are:

- How do I find a way to mimic the tufte-fonts in my documentclass?
- Do my approaches make sense or are there alternative approaches?
- How do I redefine commands and where do I find the original font definitions in the source code of the class?

Thank you everyone in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Going through tufte-common.def and tufte-book.cls I see that tufte uses the fancyhdr package. For frontmatter it uses

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@twoside}}%
  {\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}}%
  {\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\thepage}}%
```

while for mainmatter it uses

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@twoside}}%
  {% two-side
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{##1}{}}%
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\quad\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\plaintitle}}}% book title
    \fancyhead[RO]{\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\leftmark}}\quad\thepage}% chapter title
  }%
  {% one-side
    \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\plaintitle}}\quad\thepage}% book title
  }%
```

You will have to replace `\ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@twoside}}` with `\if@twoside` etc.  `\plaintitle` should be replaced by `\@title`.

I also found

```
  \IfFileExists{mathpazo.sty}{\RequirePackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}}{}
  \IfFileExists{helvet.sty}{\RequirePackage[scaled=0.90]{helvet}}{}
  \IfFileExists{beramono.sty}{\RequirePackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}}{}
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \RequirePackage{textcomp}
```

although nor for xetex or lualatex.

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint! I fonud the bibitufte-book.cls. First, I included the package: \usepackage{fancyhdr} to the Latex code.
Now, I have changed the definions of frontmatter and backmatter, e.g. like this 
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{.........}
\makeatother and also using  \if@twoside ......  \fi. Still, the fonts aren't changing. Where and how can I change them?

Comment: \smallcaps was the only thing specific to the headers.

Comment: There is a section in the tufte-common file **% Make Tuftian-style section headings and TOC formatting**
`\titleformat{\chapter}%
  [display]% shape
  {\relax\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}}% format applied to label+text
  {\itshape\huge\thechapter}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}% before the title body
  [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]% after the title body` This helps, I haven't figured it out fully, but it's another hint.

Comment: None of that refers to the header.  Only the \chaptermark definition matters, and it performs no formatting.  You might look at titlesec and titletoc (also loaded).  I never use them myself as they are redundant and too complicated.